# Mandril merge inline images

Tags: email, email-attachments, mailchimp, mandrill, inline-images

I'm trying to send a monthly snapshot of our user's activity using mandrill templates.

I want to be able to send an inline image of a graph of their activity. The image is generated on the server side and attached to the email. I can easily do this when I send to a single recipient by adding the attachment to the images property of the message object.

However, what about when I want to send a batch of emails? How can I ensure that each inline picture goes to each recipient but not to all? I've experimented with using ids in the inline markup

```
<img src="cid:image_*|recipientid|*">
```

but although this appears to work, if you open the message source, you'll see that all recipients receive all images - when I want to send a batch to 100's of people at a time, I can't see this as being very effective.

Also have tried

```
<img src="*|base64string|*">
```

Which works, however support for inline base64 images in email clients is extremely poor, so it isn't really an option.

Any help would be very appreciated.

If anyone could also tell me what kind of performance tradeoff I'm likely to get by calling the mandrillapi lots of times versus once, that would be good as I'm starting to think this may be the only way to get what I need, perhaps even dividing into batches of 10 at a time and allowing people to download the extra 9 images they don't need (I'm expecting image sizes of 10KB).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As of July 2015, this is not possible